# app permission work on samsung galaxy s5 but not on xolo A1010 (android)

Tags: android, permissions

i am running my app which uses following permission

```html
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
```

now when i run my app on samsung galaxy s5 with android 5.0 it works fine and i checked in settings on phone it shows me above all permission.But when i installed same app on xolo a1010 with android 4.4.2 it just add READ_SMS,READ_CONTACTS permssion(in Settings) and it force stop with Write_External_storage denial permission. although it works fine before on both phones.

is there any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: It's very difficult to solved device specific issue..

Comment: then add this permission if getting error...Write_External_storage

Comment: Looks like you declare READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE but app wants to WRITE to SD.

Comment: there is another problem with project i keep updating it whatever you said,but it seems it wont reflated. @RohitGoswami still giving mw same error.

Comment: but then how come it works perfectly fine with galaxy s5? @Stan

Comment: Ask Samsung :) their AOS versions usually works its own way. IMHO Samsung Android versions are most incompatible with generic/stock Android.